# How to read plain text content with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

The source file contains

```
Hello World, this is a nice world
```

The output desired applying the XSLT to the input file:

```
<Hello_World message="this is a nice world"/>
```

I know I can use `unparsed-text` in XSLT 2.0 easily, but I need do it with XSLT 1.0.

I browsed a while, and I can't find something useful.

Is it posible? I need to use Xalan XSLT processor.

I think this question is challenging.

Comment: Can you pre-process the source file and wrap it with an element? Like `<doc>` + `source file contents` + `</doc>`

Comment: I can't but the answer of @kjhughes is what i need to know: I can't do what i need.

Comment: I wonder: XSLT is intended for XML processing, but your input does not look like XML at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible for the input document to be plain text because *the input to an XSLT 1.0 transformation must be well-formed XML*.

Here are some alternative ways to access plain text in an XSLT transformation:

- Use [**unparsed-text**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-xslt20-20011220/#function-unparsed-text) in **XSLT 2.0**.
- Pass the plain text in via [**top-level parameters** (`xsl:param`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#top-level-variables).
- **Preprocess the text file** to turn it into a well-formed XML document.
- Generate the XSLT file dynamically, possibly via a **meta XSLT transformation**, and include the plain text directly in the XSLT source.  Then just use a dummy XML input file.
- Reference the text file as an **external entity** in a wrapper XML
  document, and then process the wrapper XML document using XSLT.

Here's an example of the **external entity** technique:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE wrapper [
<!ENTITY textFile SYSTEM "file.txt">
]>
<wrapper>&textFile;</wrapper>
```

(Note that this last option could be challenging given XSLT 1.0's limited string processing abilities, but for some data, it may be viable.)