# Firefox xslt unparsed-text() function error

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying something simple, to load a text file using the xsl given below (a trimmed down version of the actual file):

## xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"               
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="file" >
    <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text(@path,'utf-8')" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sql.xsl" ?>
  <file path="sql/41_routine_xyz.sql" />
```

I get the error:

> Error during XSLT transformation: An unknown XPath extension function was called.

Is it even possible in firefox? If not, what are the possibilities?

Comment: No browser supports XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Michael.hor257k is correct that no browser supports XSLT 2.0 *natively*.  Use [Saxon-CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml) for a JavaScript implementation of XSLT 2.0 suitable for use in browsers, or use the XSLT 1.0 alternatives for reading plain text listed in the [link provided by Mathias](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20109910/290085).

Comment: I wonder how this question is duplicate given the context of firefox and xslt 2.0 :( However ,thank for the link