# Blank (empty) input XML file to XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

In my situation I have a automated XSLT (1.0) running, transforming files to a SOAP format and pushing them over a WSDL. However, because the source is unreliable for good input data sometimes the XML files I have to pick up and process are blank. Is there a way to inject these files a value during transformation and output or ignore these blank files?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "blank"?  Do you mean a file with literally zero content (zero bytes), or do you mean a file that has XML elements, but none of them are populated?  If the former, I don't think any pure XSL engine will accept empty files -- Saxon, for instance, spits out a `Premature end of file` error if the input file is completely empty.  If the input file has content that isn't valid, well-formed XML, Saxon spits out different errors.  How are you processing the files?

Comment: If a file is "blank" then it isn't an XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the input to an XSLT 1.0 transformation must be a well-formed XML document, and to be well-formed, an XML document must be have single root element.  Therefore, your transformation cannot take a blank (empty) document as input.

Fix the broken source of the empty "XML" documents, or pre-process the file before it hits the XSLT transformation.

See also **[How to read plain text content with XSLT 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109910/how-to-read-plain-text-content-with-xslt-1-0)** for some additional alternatives.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this is what I feared but I couldn't find a solid answer anywhere.