# Embeding a CSS file using XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

At the moment this is how I include a CSS file in my XSL script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-Keynsham.css"/>
```

It is added in the `<head>` section. So I end up with something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-Keynsham.css" />
    <title>OUR CHRISTIAN LIFE AND MINISTRY (Midweek Meeting August 2017)</title>
  </head>
```

But, now I want to do it differently. For reasons, I want to **embed** the CSS stylesheet that that it is physically part of the resulting HTML output. Eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>OUR CHRISTIAN LIFE AND MINISTRY (Midweek Meeting August 2017)</title>
    <style type="text/css">
body {
    width: 680px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Calibri, "Calibri Light", Arial, SansSerif;
    background: #666666;
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
}
    </style>
  </head>
```

How do I do that with my XSL script?

## Update

This is how I do the transform:

```
   XslCompiledTransform myXslTransform;
    myXslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    myXslTransform.Load("d:\\My Test\\UHD\\Workbook-Keynsham.xsl");
    myXslTransform.Transform("d:\\My Test\\UHD\\test.xml", "d:\\My Test\\UHD\\testtransform.html");
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to pull the style information from the .css file into the generated HTML? If so, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20110529/317052 . Otherwise, just replace the `link` element in your stylesheet with the `style` element that contains the css.

Comment: @DanielHaley I want to pull the information. I looked at the link you gave me. I have updated my question with how I do the transform. I don't know if `XslCompiledTransform` is xsl-2 compliant?

Comment: @DanielHaley I see that the MSDN says: The XslCompiledTransform class is an XSLT processor that supports the XSLT 1.0 syntax.

Comment: I don't use .NET, but I'm certain XslCompiledTransform does not support 2.0. However, Saxon is available for .NET and supports 2.0 (and 3.0). See http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.8HE and http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/gettingstarted/gettingstarteddotnet.html for getting started. Saxon and XSLT 2.0+ will blow your mind compared to XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks. Is this saxon approach something I can deploy to remote users with my application?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't. Like I said I don't know .NET or how you're deploying, but from a Saxon perspective you shouldn't have a problem. (Be sure to read/include the proper license files included with Saxon.)

Comment: Saxon HE .NET is also on NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE/ although that is not an official package by Saxonica, instead done by Max Toro.

Comment: And of course the parameter approach with e.g. `<xsl:param name="css-text"/>` and e.g `<style><xsl:value-of select="$css-text"/></style>` works with any XSLT 1.0 processor, in .NET with XslCompiledTransform the `Transform` method has overloads taking an `XsltArgumentList`. And pulling in the CSS into a string with your .NET code running the transformation to set the parameter should be easy.